# "extra shading pie menu items" option not showing in custom keymap

Tags: shaders

In Blender 2.80 in *Properties > Keymap* if you use the standard Blender preset you get Preferences windows with option to check "**extra shading pie menu items**" option under *Tilde Action*. This option extends the shading pie menu

But when you use a custom Keymap the preference window is unavailable.

Is there a way to turn this option on other way?

I tried using python line that I got from the Info window but I only get en error

```
>>> bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].(null) = True
  File "<blender_console>", line 1
    bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].(null) = True
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

The "extra shading pie menu items" is available if you manually change the keymap name from `VIEW3D_MT_shading_pie` to `VIEW3D_MT_shading_ex_pi`